# Snow Leopard resets sound volume whenever I start my computer

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, audio

I've recently installed Snow Leopard in my MacBook. I made a clean installation, although I restored some data and settings from a Time Machine backup, and the first weird thing I noticed was that the «Welcome video» had no sound at all.

I've discovered later that **the sound was disabled/muted whenever Snow Leopard started**, although I could listen the [startup chime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chime_(Macintosh)) anyway. It was perfectly possible to enable the sound again just by pressing a button, but this issue was kind of weird.

I've found in a [forum](http://forums.mactalk.com.au/46/72243-snow-leopard-sound-bug.html) people with the same problem. Some users even experience their sound volume reseted to a specific value. How can this be solved?

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer! (Or first make that answer Community Wiki if you feel bad about accepting your own solution.)

Comment: Oh, I've just forgot! Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [forum](http://forums.mactalk.com.au/46/72243-snow-leopard-sound-bug.html) suggests that this could be an issue with some setting files. The solution seems to be simple, fortunately:

> In **Macintosh HD / Library / Preferences / Audio** there are two audio setting files. Delete them. Set your sound to the desired setting. Restart.

The directory may contain some copies of the setting files "tagged" with *~orig*. You can delete them as well.